# Product of two lists with conditionals

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to find a concise way to construct a list of tuples of combinations from two lists. Consider the lists:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [0, 3, 4, 5]
```

The objective is to get a list like:

```py
[(None, 0), (1, None), (2, None), (3, 3), (None, 4), (None, 5)]
```

So, matching pairs go together, and if there is no corresponding element in one list, then it should be filled in by something (here, `None`).

`zip` and `itertools.zip_longest` don't work here, and `itertools.product` obviously returns all the combinations of the lists, which needs quite a lot of post-filtering to get the right combinations.

I have tried:

```py
prods = product(x, y)
matches = [ (i,j) for prods if i==j ]
unmatches = []
for i, j in prods:
   if i != j and (i, None) not in unmatches:
      unmatches += [ (i, None) ]
   elif i != j and (None, j) not in unmatches:
      unmatches += [ (None, j) ]
```

However, this returns:

```py
matches 
# [(3,3)]
unmatches
# [ (1, None), (None, 3), (None, 4), (None, 5), (2, None), (3, None) ]
```

because of how `product` returns the products (e.g. no `(0, j)` terms).

Is there a easy way?

Comment: What should happen in case there are duplicates for example `x = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3]`?

Comment: Is there always exactly one matching pair?

Comment: The problem is thinking about this problem in terms of *products*. Its is not the products you should be after.

Comment: @Daweo I hadn't thought about that, but I think duplicates should be included, i.e. `(1, None), (1, None) ...`

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension is the way:

```
[(i if i in x else None, i if i in y else None) for i in range(1, max(x + y) + 1)]
```

Gives:

```
[(None, 0), (1, None), (2, None), (3, 3), (None, 4), (None, 5)]
```

Comment: although this does produce the desired result, it makes assumptions that are not explicitly mentioned in the question. That being said, it is a nice list comprehension which may very well be the solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: Thanks. Although, I won't always have sequential series of numbers across the lists.

Answer (score 0):

`list comprehension` and `set` may help you.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [0, 3, 4, 5]
x = set(x)
y = set(y)
u = x.intersection(y)
diff = x - y
diff_2 = y - x
t = [(i, None) for i in diff] + [(i, i) for i in u] + [(None, i) for i in diff_2]

print(t)
```

**Result:**

```
[(1, None), (2, None), (3, 3), (None, 0), (None, 4), (None, 5)]
```